# Is there an option to implicitly localise labels in Interfacebuilder

Tags: ios, xcode, internationalization, interface-builder

Somewhere in a blog post I stumbled upon a strings file which looked like this:

```
// de.lproj/Localizable.strings
"This is the title" = "Das ist der Titel"
```

To me this looked like the actual labels in Interface builder were processed by the compiler so that no explicit translations using `NSLocalizedString(@"SOME_IDENTIFIER", @"");` would be necessary any more.

My question now, is whether there is some kind of shortcut or do I need to localise all my individual labels on my view e.g. in the `awakeFromNib` method.

Comment: Apple has documentation: [Preparing Your Nib Files for Localization](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LocalizingInterfaces.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out a way to semi-automate the process so that I don't have to do this:

```
label1.text = NSLocalizedString(@"label1_key", @"");
label2.text = NSLocalizedString(@"label2_key", @"");
....
labeln.text = NSLocalizedString(@"labeln_key", @"");
```

So for all labels which should be localised I set their text to `__KeyForLabelX` in IB. Then in the `viewWillAppear` method of the viewcontroller I loop through the items on the view and set the text to the localized value:

```
for (UIView *view in self.view){
    if([view isMemberOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
        UILabel *l = (UILabel *)view;

        BOOL shouldTranslate = [l.text rangeOfString:@"__"].location != NSNotFound;
        NSString *key = [l.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"__" withString:@"TranslationPrefix"];
        if (shouldTranslate){
            l.text = NSLocalizedString(key, @"");
        }
    }
}
```

My .strings file then look like this:

```
"TranslationPrefixKeyForLabelX" = "Translation of Label X";
```

**Update:** To further adapt the mechanism you could also check for other `UIView`s like `UIButtons`, `UITextField`s (including prompt text) etc.

Comment: Using a similar idea I have created an automated tool that runs on awakeFromNib and autotranslates all your IB components. Check it out here: https://github.com/angelolloqui/AGi18n