# Localized String with Interface Builder User Defined Runtime Attributes

Tags: ios, ios7, interface-builder, nslocalizedstring, uiaccessibility

[image: Storyboard]

I am currently trying to create a localized accessibilityLabel in the storyboard (I am trying to avoid doing it programatically). It seems that whenever I use the Localized String option, the accessibilityLabels ends up being set to the localized string key that I have provided rather than the string itself. Does anyone have the solution to this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Localize a view within a storyboard using "User Defined Runtime Attributes"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779881/localize-a-view-within-a-storyboard-using-user-defined-runtime-attributes) (which concluded that this is a carryover from OS X and not supported on iOS).

Comment: I was really hoping that someone would have some more insight into this issue after all this time. I have read this topic and I was really hoping that that wasn't the case.

Comment: Note that you can still localize whole Interface Builder files like any other resource.

Comment: I'm relatively new to iOS development, but is the storyboard file considered an IB file?

Comment: Ah, in this case, you'll want to enable [`Use Base Internationalization`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12731497/401774) and then create a strings file for each localization.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you expect the localized string to be taken from Localizable.strings. The "Localized String" type doesn't work this way, it's just a marker to indicate that the value of the user defined runtime attribute will participate in the localization process when you use base localization. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24527990/2876231 for a lengthier explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute type needs to be `Localizable String`, and then you'd translate it in the `.strings` file using the following property:

```
"KLc-fp-ZVK.ibExternalUserDefinedRuntimeAttributesLocalizableStrings[0]" = "¡Hola!";
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work with a named attribute, but only with the long property above.

(Based on Andrew's answer here: [Localize a view within a storyboard using "User Defined Runtime Attributes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779881/localize-a-view-within-a-storyboard-using-user-defined-runtime-attributes))

Answer (score 0):

I did the customization of an attribute with the simple solution of localizing the attribute by code:

```
private struct AssociatedKeys {
    static var someTagKey = "someTag"
}

@IBInspectable var someTag: String? {
    get {
       return NSLocalizedString(
            objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.someTagsKey) as? String ?? "", comment: "")
    }
    set {
        if let newValue = newValue {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(
                self,
                &AssociatedKeys.someTagsKey,
                newValue as NSString?,
                objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC
            )
        }
    }
}
```

And after that you can easily extract all the strings from the xib and storyboard files with an egrep:

```
egrep -ohr --include="*.xib" --include="*.storyboard" '<userDefinedRuntimeAttribute type="string" keyPath="someTag" value="[^"]+"/>' . >> extracted-strings.txt
```

And after that eliminate the tags in the strings file by the following sed and then you have to plain strings file for xcode ready:

```
sed -i -e 's/^<userDefinedRuntimeAttribute type="string" keyPath="someTag" value=\("[^"]*"\)\/>/\1 = \1;/g' extracted-strings.txt
```