# IBDesignable localisable strings

Tags: ios, xcode, internationalization, interface-builder

I'm using Xcode's export for localisation feature, and I have a custom `IBDesignable` UIControl with a `IBInspectable` string. I'm wondering if there's a way to include this string to the exported `.xliff` file.

Answer (score 2):

In the `User Defined Runtime Attribute`, you can set the type to localized string. And this allow the string to be included in the exported file. However, I haven't found a way to make the field default to localized string type, so you'll need to change the type every time by yourself.

Comment: In case somebody else also comes across this after such a long time: Unfortunately the iOS runtime does not use the ultimately generated `.strings` files for this, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24527990/710041. :(